# GStreamer 1.21. qtmux produces garbage on recording plain H.264 when resolution changes

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, recording

This is the pipeline:

```
webrtcbin name=webrtcbin bundle-policy=max-bundle! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! qtmuxfragment-duration=1000 ! filesink location=/home/ubuntu/recordings/abcde/test.mkv
```

Modern browsers vary resolution and bitrate during the startup phase of a session. It is not uncommon to see 640x360 for a while, followed by 960x540 up to maybe 1280x720 later in a H.264 stream.

Trying to record this to disk requires the use of either mp4mux or qtmux. Both did break up the recording on the first resolution change in versions prior GStreamer 1.20. Practically this was the end of the recording when the first change from 640x360 to 960x540 happened.

Meanwhile (after 1.20) the qtmux survives the renegotiation with upstream, but the downstream does not contain the required (and updated) SPS/PPS. Just the IDR frame (initiated by the browser) is sent downstream. In the end this means, that after the first resolution change there is only garbage in the output file.

Any idea, how this could be changed?

Comment: _"After the first resolution change there is only garbage in the output file."_ That is caused by the H264 decoder using the wrong SPS & PPS (is always taken from first resolution?). You really need to somehow provide a new updated SPS & PPS to account for the new resolution (and also it's possible that the incoming data is now also having a different H264 profile). I don't use GStreamer so it's not obvious to me what is your input (it's an M3U8 file?)... If M3U8 then I would just extract the link for the preferred resolution or recreate a modified version listing only your wanted resolution.

Comment: Input is a H.264 webrtc stream from Chrome. It is terminated in a WebRtcEndpoint in Kurento Media Server. I'm sure this SPS/PPS is in, because if I redirect the RTP stream to an RTSP server and consume the video from there, the client perfectly gets SPS/PPS/IDR on resolution change. But I will try to record the bitstream directly behind rtph264depay and try to decode that with some tools. Thanks for the response

Comment: Yes, it is in. Perfectly. I now stopped messing with GStreamer to do the H.264 -> MP4 conversion. Instead I'm using a spawned FFMpeg process, which does that perfectly.

Comment: You're quick. Most would not debug within 24hrs, never mind your impossible "within 1 hour" fix. Glad it's solved. PS: I know MPEG better but was going to comment to say I suspect MKV stores SPS/PPS once in main header and I suspect Gstreamer ignores future multiple SPS/PPS since in H264 they can be re-transmitted every X-amount of frames (_eg:_ live streams with later connections during streaming of bytes). Gstreamer must be just seeing a label like "SPS" and skipping to a frame since it has that SPS already. It never checks if the actual content is different though.

Comment: :) I was already hunting this down since several days. I have skimmed the mp4mux and qtmux implementations of GStreamer (1.18.4, the version I'm using and 1.21). The older versions didn't even bother about caps changes and refuses to re-negotiate if the new cap set isn't a 1:1 sub-set of the old (or vice versa, don't fully recall). In 1.21 they at least consider to acknowledge things like width and height changes (which in older versions did lead to and end of everything event). But since they don't forward the new SPS/PPS in the stream (just IDR), the decoder just sees garbage.

Comment: Here is the code in question: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/20bbeb5e37666c53c254c7b08470ad8a00d97630/gst/isomp4/gstqtmux.c#L5771

Comment: Check the comment :) /* does not go well to renegotiate stream mid-way, unless
   * the old caps are a subset of the new one (this means upstream
   * added more info to the caps, as both should be 'fixed' caps) */